# Transport Motorcycle from Barcelona to Toronto

Tags: canada, driving

I'm planning on moving to Toronto for a year (maybe more) and I intend to bring my motorcycle with me so I can have some self flexibility (visit Niagara Falls, Detroit, Cleveland, Montreal...).

I'd like to know, in your experience, what is the best way (ferry, plane or others) and costs of doing so.

Bear in mind I don't mind driving it a bit if needed. This means that in case of being a ferry, I could depart from Barcelona to New York and drive to Toronto, or for example depart from Lisboa. This applies both for ferries and planes (imagine this kind of flights depart only from Madrid, no problem driving there).

Key doubts:

- Costs
- Route (can be flexible as said)
- Paperwork (a European licensed motorcycle in Canada implies some paperwork I believe)

Thanks

Comment: I think this question fits better on our expats sister site. I will move it there for you.

Comment: There's a discussion regarding transfering a car from Europe to North America over on Travel SE. Maybe this gives some insights: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/882/shipping-my-car-from-europe-to-canada-or-the-u-s

Comment: You might find it dramatically simpler, and cheaper, to sell your motorcycle in Spain and buy a new one in Canada...

Comment: There will be a significant difference between bringing your bike to Canada temporarily as a tourist (i.e., for six months or less, presuming you're an EU citizen), and bringing your bike to Canada as a permanent import for a longer period. The former will be relatively easy, the latter a lot more difficult.

Comment: I hope you're aware that the weather here isn't like in Spain.  For half the year you likely won't be able to use a motorcycle.  But if you do bring it, be sure to visit [Friday the 13th motorcycle rally - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_motorcycle_rally) in Port Dover.